# How to do responsive HTML canvas within div

Tags: html, css, canvas

I have three divs. First and third div have Next - Previous button. Second means center div has an HTML canvas. So I want to make it responsive. But the maximum canvas height should be 400px and maximum width should be 300px.
check this fiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/4zx732ug/1/

```
<div>
<div class="left"> First Div </div>
<div class="middle">
<canvas  id="myCanvas"  height="400" width="300"   style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="right"> Third Div </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.left {
float: left;
background-color: #ddd;
}

.middle {
background-color: yellow;
float: left;
}

.right {
float: left;
background-color: #ddd;
}
```

So how do I make this div responsive with canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<div class="left"> First Div </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <canvas  id="myCanvas"  height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="right"> Third Div </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.middle {
    background-color: yellow;
   float: left;
   border:1px solid #000000;
   width: 300px;
}
.right {
    float: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
@media all and (max-width: 450px) {
    .middle {
        width: calc(69% - 10px);
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 410px){
    .middle {
        width: calc(67% - 10px);
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 360px){
    .middle {
        width: calc(60% - 10px);
    }
}
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4zx732ug/3/)</kbd>**

Comment: Height is not resizing. Also height should be resizable like width

Comment: You can set this in every @media

Comment: And all three div should be in horizontally. Div is changing to vertically.

Answer (score 0):

To make the canvas follow the div, assuming you have applied CSS to the div (important for this to work), you can use the div's bounding client-rectangle to make the *bitmap* match the size of this parent div.

Call when DOM has loaded to initialize, as well as on window's resize events:

```
var rect = document.querySelector(".middle").getBoundingClientRect();
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

canvas.width  = Math.max(1, Math.min(400, rect.width));
canvas.height = Math.max(1, Math.min(300, rect.height));
```

As canvas bitmap cannot be smaller than 1 pixel also force clamping at this end.